# must be vs must - Why use one over the other

Tags: phrase-origin

What is the explanation for the construction of the phrases "it must be valid" and "it must exist" that are frequently used without much thought, and why haven't we created alternative versions such as "it must valid" or "it must be exist"?

In both sentences, "valid or validity of the item", and "exist- existence of the item" are preconditions for something to happen, and to me the skeleton of both sentences looks same, yet they are constructed differently. Any idea?

Comment: Valid is an adjective, exist is a verb.

Comment: "Valid" is an adjective and "exist" is a verb. Something can't "be" a verb, nor can it "do" an adjective.

Comment: ok, so we can say, "it must validate", right?

Comment: “It must be valid” is just fine.

Comment: Must as a modal verb is always followed by another verb. https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/must-english-modal-verb/

Comment: yup, thats why i asked about "it must validate", we prefer it not either (normally), even though 'validate' is a verb.

Comment: “It must validate” is correct, but it lacks an object.

Comment: *It must validate* is somewhat ambiguous - when I shove my bank card into the ATM which *must validate*, the card or the ATM? If, as some do, you think that the verb *validate* requires an object then the sentence must mean that the machine validates the card.  Which is not quite the same as saying that the card must be valid.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark "Validate" can be used as an unaccusative (ergative) verb, e.g. "your card must validate before you can proceed." [See Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/validate)

Comment: @alphabet: OED, and I, beg to differ ... but I'm not sure our disagreement affects the potential ambiguity of *It must validate*

Answer (score 1):

If you replace "must" with "will," you'll have your answer:

> 1. It will be valid.
> 2. It will exist.
> 3. *It will valid.
> 4. *It will be exist.

Sentence (3) is wrong because it has no main verb. Sentence (4) is wrong because it has two main verbs. Only (1) and (2) are correct.

The auxiliary verb "must" works the same way as "will" in this respect.